# Softmatx activation in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I am new to Keras.

I want to build a CNN network with Keras.

It is fine until I want to add a softmax dense layer.

The error is `TypeError: softmax() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`.

I searched Keras and tried to fix it:

```
from keras.layers import Softmax
output_layer = Dense(units=n_classes, activation=Softmax(axis=-1),  kernel_initializer='uniform')
```

However, it still gives error plus the warning:

`UserWarning: Do not pass a layer instance (such as Softmax) as the activation argument of another layer. Instead, advanced activation layers should be used just like any other layer in a model.`

What is the correct method of applying softmax?

Thank you very much.

```
cnn = Sequential()
kernelSize = (3, 3)
ip_activation = 'relu'
ip_conv_0 = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=kernelSize, input_shape=im_shape, activation=ip_activation)
cnn.add(ip_conv_0)
ip_conv_0_1 = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=kernelSize, activation=ip_activation)
cnn.add(ip_conv_0_1)
pool_0 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")
cnn.add(pool_0)
drop_layer_0 = Dropout(0.2)
cnn.add(drop_layer_0)
flat_layer_0 = Flatten()
cnn.add(Flatten())
h_dense_0 = Dense(units=128, activation=ip_activation, kernel_initializer='uniform')
cnn.add(h_dense_0)
h_dense_1 = Dense(units=64, activation=ip_activation, kernel_initializer='uniform')
cnn.add(h_dense_1)

op_activation = 'softmax'
output_layer = Dense(units=n_classes, activation=op_activation, kernel_initializer='uniform')
cnn.add(output_layer)#<---------error

TypeError: softmax() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass the axis argument to softmax?

Comment: I just tried to write somethings to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

Keras differ between the layer softmax and the activation function softmax. [See here.](https://keras.io/activations/) As the error suggests you are trying to pass a whole layer where a function is needed. The most simple solution would be to just pass a string:

```
output_layer = Dense(units=500, activation='softmax',  kernel_initializer='uniform')
```

Another possibility would be to pass no activation function to the layer and apply an Activation layer afterwards.